# Datatable infinite scroll data is not added to new row, its replace old 10 data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

im using c# and jquery datatable to make infinite scroll with my data. I successfully get new 10 data from my backend controller, but the data is not append or added as a new row, its replace the old 10 data.

This is my Index.cshtml code:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="@Url.Action("","")"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 row">
                            <h3 class="box-title" style="margin-top:5px;">
                                @ViewBag.Title
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <table id="oTable" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var start = 0;
        var length = 10; // Initial number of rows to display
        var totalCount = 0; // Total number of records available
        var loadingData = false;
        var data = [];

        var tbl = $('#oTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            serverSide: true,
            scrollY: 300, // Specify the desired height of the table
            paging: false,
            processing: true,
            scroller: {
                loadingIndicator: true
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'Data1', title: 'DATA 1'},
                { data: 'Data2', title: 'DATA 2'},
            ],
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyControllerName")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (data) {
                    data.start = start;
                    data.length = length;
                },
                dataSrc: function (response) {
                    totalCount = response.recordsTotal;
                    return response.data;
                }
            }
        });

        // Detect scroll event on the DataTable wrapper
        $('.dataTables_scrollBody').on('scroll', function () {
            var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
            var tableHeight = $(this).height();
            var contentHeight = $(this).get(0).scrollHeight;
            // Check if the scroll position is near the bottom of the table
            if (scrollPos + tableHeight >= contentHeight - 10) {
                if (!loadingData && tbl.data().count() < totalCount) {
                    // Load more data
                    loadingData = true;
                    start += length;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyControllerName")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            start: start,
                            length: length,
                            draw: tbl.ajax.json().draw // Pass the draw parameter from the previous request
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            tbl.rows.add(response.data).draw(false);
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            loadingData = false;
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Error loading data.');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have try to find the solution in Google, but i cant found the same problem.

Comment: Do you use `F12` to see any error message ?